# C# ListView Grouping binding error

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I failed to perform grouping in list view. It shows error code as:

> BindingExpression path error:  Indicator' property not found on 'object' ''CollectionViewGroupInternal'`.

may I know which part of my code is wrong?

Below is the class code:

Data are pulled from the database.

```
foreach(string value in getCountry)
{
    string[] values = value.Split(',');
    string countryname = values[0].ToString();
    string indicator = values[1].ToString();
    items.Add(new User() { CountryName = countryname, Indicator = indicator });
}

lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Indicator"); //i expect error is from here
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);



public class User
{
            public string CountryName { get; set; }
            public string Indicator { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the XAML CODE:

```
    <ListView Name="lvUsers" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Arial">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
              <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CountryName}" />
              <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Indicator}" />
            </GridView>
         </ListView.View>
   <ListView.GroupStyle>
   <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Indicator}" FontSize="30"  FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Black"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
   </ListView.GroupStyle>
   </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `HeaderTemplate`, the binding property should be `Name` rather than `Indicator`.

```
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30"  FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="Black"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Hi, there is no name in user class

Comment: The `Name` property is from the `CollectionViewGroup` class, which is the parent of `CollectionViewGroupInternal`. A group of `Users` is wrapped as a `CollectionViewGroupInternal` so that the binding property should from the `CollectionViewGroupInternal` rather than the `User`.

Comment: Noted! thanks for the explanation ! i thought the Name property is binding value.